# Safe reboot cron job with fallback on SysRq reset issue

Tags: cron, reboot

I'm trying to setup a cron job to reboot devices daily. With a safe callback to a SysRq reset if for some reason the reboot does hang (issue being that SSH gets killed and the device never reboots so it is lost and requires costly human intervention to restart).

The script that used to work for a while:

```
5 5 * * * root /sbin/reboot -f; sleep 30; /bin/echo `date -u +'\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%SZ'` >> /var/log/player-reboot.error.log; echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; sync; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

However it's pretty brutal (hard reboot -f) and some of our devices did not recover recently (a couple over thousands every day).

Not sure what hangs (looks like the file is never written so I'd say either the reboot itself or the echo hangs?

Was looking to use ampersands & to never "lock" and be sure that a proper reset will happen eventually, however it does not seem to work at all (no more reboots):

```
5 5 * * * root /sbin/shutdown -r +2 &; sleep 240; /bin/echo `date -u +'\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%SZ'` >> /var/log/player-reboot.error.log &; echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; sleep 1; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Can I use the ampersand in a cron script?
Do you know another smarter way to achieve the desired results?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the current issue is, but I'd be tempted to write a single script, which triggers the various things.  I'm always wary of essentially writing mini-scripts as the cron command itself, easier IMO to write a proper script and just call that.

Comment: Assuming your machine uses systemd, I don't think you can background (&) a call to '/sbin/shutdown'. It's essentially an internal call to an AF_UNIX socket that implements the shutdown process. If you're on a machine that uses 'telinit' (i.e., Upstart or SysV init), you could use '/sbin/telinit 6' followed by the rest of your invocation. But a script would be better.